# How should i define "max" or "all" at a deposit command. (discordpy)

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so im making a deposit command for my currency game, but im stuck with it. How should i do this?

```
if amount == "max" or "all":
            amount = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
            await self.update_bank(ctx.author,-amount,"wallet")
            await self.update_bank(ctx.author, +amount,"bank")
```

> Traceback:

```
Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'max'
```

Comment: `if amount == "max" or "all"` is not the right way to test for two values.  Use `if amount == "max" or "amount == "all"` instead, or even better `if amount in ["max", "all"]`

Comment: is max or all supposed to be a variable containing an int?

Comment: The answer is simple you are getting value as str . convert it to int

Answer (score -2):

Your `if` statement is wrong, assuming the type of `amount` is `int`.

It should be:

```
if str(amount) == "max" or str(amount) == "all":
....
```

Comment: If amount is an int, how would str ever equal "max" or "all"?

Comment: If you assume that amount is int then the if statement you wrote here can never be executed.

Comment: you both are correct should have commented not answered.